# C++ wrapper for boost/c++11

Tags: c++, boost, c++11

I am not sure the title of the question is proper. Here is the problem. I am writing a library which use some c++11 library features. Clearly not all implementations support these libraries yet and thus there is the portability problem. It does not matter which library is of concern here. One solution is to use boost, which already provide a lot c++11 libraries. So my solution is to define a macro, say `USE_CXX11`, and define a new namespace say `internal` and introduce names into this internal namespace dependent on the macros. For example say I need to use a name `foo` from a c++ library `<foo>`, which is also available in `<boost/foo/foo.hpp>`. What I do is

```
#ifdef USE_CXX11
#include <foo>
#else
#include <boost/foo/foo.hpp>
#endif

namespace internal {
#ifdef USE_CXX11
using std::foo;
#else
using boost::foo::foo;
#endif
}
```

And in the rest of the library I only use `internal::foo`. Third party code which use this library can define the proper macro to indicate if they have a working c++ 11 implementation or they can only use boost. And my library will pickup the right header and namespace. This works so far. Hope I have explained my intention well.

But the above solutions seems very ugly to me. Is there any better practice for this kind of thing? Or is there any possible situations that this approach will not work?

Comment: If it's in Boost, and you need to support outdated compilers, just use the one in Boost directly.

Comment: I need to support both old compilers using boost and new ones who don't want to use boost for any reason (who knows?) boost tr1 is not a solution. For example libc++ does not have tr1 at all, it aims at c++11 from the start. So there is still the two namespace problem.

Comment: I thought about just use boost for a really long time. And that was the way the project started. But later I found all the things I use are also available in c++11. So I think it would be good not to force a third party dependence if the user have a recent compiler. In fact, if I require boost then I need to require at least boost 1.49, which is the most recent release, and outdate most Linux distributions. Even the recent released fedora 17 only have boost 1.48. So by forcing boost I need the user to install boost themselves which not everyone want to, while libstdc++ come with gcc4.6 is ok

Comment: Just use Boost if it's that helpful. If you only wanted a single class or something, then I'd say remake it. But if someone is going to use C++, they need to be both competent and willing enough to install Boost. The only side effect of doing so is that you now have a useful collection of libraries at your disposal.

Comment: @GManNickG The other problem is that boost do not work as well as recent c++11 implementations. For example, the random library still have some bugs, which affects the results mathematically. Such bugs are also related to non-standard conforming behaviors. These problem does not exist in recent libstdc++ or libc++ or msvc 10. So I only want boost as a backup.

Comment: This is actually a scientific computing library. And at a later stage the library will provide an R interface. That is what people will really use, (though a few may use the C++ API for performance and flexibility as it is template library). So the choice between Boost and std will be made at the time the R package is built, and automatically chosen by the build system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your solution looks fine to me; the only problem will be (as Chet mentions) in the cases where the Boost and C++11 interfaces and/or implementations differ.

In fact, I do that in the Boost.Algorithms library (new in the upcoming 1.50 release)

```
namespace boost { namespace algorithm {
#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
using std::find_if_not;      // Section 25.2.5
#else
template<typename InputIterator, typename Predicate> 
InputIterator find_if_not ( InputIterator first, InputIterator last, Predicate p )
{
    for ( ; first != last; ++first )
        if ( !p(*first))
            break;
    return first;
}
#endif
}}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't see this as a workable solution. Conditionally switching between classes will restrict their use to only those member functions having the same signatures and semantics. You are also redirecting access to The Standard Library which may feel unnatural for many developers.

If usability is a concern between C++03 and C++11 then you should definitely go with Boost for everything. If C++11 is your only target you may have better success evaluating the various compilers to see what language and library features they support. Pick those that are well supported and considered bug free. For everything else use Boost and refactor later if necessary to support more C++11 library features. You will be much better off using the libraries in tandem rather than switching between them.

You can get a start with the status page of [GCC's C++ Standard Library implementation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.200x) .